# What is the command to retrieve the pass phrase of an encrypted home directory?

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs, password-recovery

I remember setting a password to encrypt my directory when I installed Ubuntu, and running a command to retrieve a pass phrase in case I lost the password. Can anyone tell me what is the terminal command to retrieve the pass phrase?

Comment: you are using ecryptfs?

Answer (score 3):

```
ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase
```

from the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase.1.html).